# ¿Por qué el `for` me duplica esta variable?

Tags: python-3.x, lista, bucle-for

Voy a tratar de explicar el problema, tengo una lista de listas en la que la recorro con un `for`, así:

```py
#TA_rep=[[1, 3], [2, 4], [3, 1], [4, 2]]


def elim_listas_rep():
    for fila in TA_rep:
        aux=fila
        aux.reverse()
        print("aux: ",aux)
        print("fila: ",fila)
```

donde `fila` es la fila de una tabla; no voy a explicar mucho el por qué del codigo para no embarrar tanto la situación. La cuestión es que por alguna razón `aux` siempre vale lo mismo que `fila`... es decir, si modifico algo de `aux`, también se modifica en `fila` y no entiendo por qué! Quiero que ambos sean independientes.

Ignoren los `print`, sólo los puse para observar qué pasaba durante el ciclo.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Pero cuando haces un =, es como si fueran lo mismo, no estas copiando el valor, si no la referencia ;)

Comment: Si quieres crear una copia, debes agregar `.copy()` , osea  a `fila.copy()`

Answer (score 4):

El problema es que cuando haces una asignación utilizando el operador `=` estás copiando el valor por referencia cuando lo usas con diccionarios o con listas. Esto se refiere a que tu variable va a apuntar al mismo bloque de memoria. Si quieres hacer una asignación que haga una copia de la lista por su valor y no por su referencia, deberás usar la función `deepcopy`.

Con esto tu código quedaría así:

```
from copy import deepcopy
TA_rep = [[1, 3], [2, 4], [3, 1], [4, 2]]

def elim_listas_rep():
    for fila in TA_rep:
        aux = deepcopy(fila)
        aux.reverse()
        print("aux: ",aux)
        print("fila: ",fila)

elim_listas_rep()
```

Si importas solo copy así:
`import copy`

Tendrás que usarlo como
`copy.deepcopy(<variable>)` para hacer tu copia.

Comment: Gracias me sirvió.

Comment: Puedes agradecérselo aceptando la respuesta (pulsando el tick verde debajo de la puntuación)